# Gmail thread object unexpected behavior

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a Google Apps Script that will process all emails that have a specific label.

I am using the GmailApp.search function to retrieve all of the relevant emails, but when I try to use the functions document in the [GmailThread class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread), I get an error message that says that it can't find the function.

Here is my code;

```
var incoming = "To_Bot"

function readBotsEmail()
{
  var emails = GmailApp.search("label:" + incoming);

  Logger.log("This is the 'emails' object:" + emails)


  var emailsLoopIndex = 0
  for (var email in emails)
  {
    emailsLoopIndex += 1;
    try
    {
      Logger.log("iteration " + emailsLoopIndex + "     " + email.getMessageCount());
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      Logger.log("iteration " + emailsLoopIndex + "     " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the logger output.

```
[14-01-26 03:40:00:909 EST] This is the 'emails' object:GmailThread,GmailThread
[14-01-26 03:40:00:911 EST] iteration 1     TypeError: Cannot find function getMessageCount in object 0.
[14-01-26 03:40:00:914 EST] iteration 2     TypeError: Cannot find function getMessageCount in object 1.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using ambiguous variable names, "email" and "emails" are really bad choice when talking about threads on one side and index integer on the other...

Your issue comes mainly from this confusion between both variables, you used email instead of email**S** and also seem to forget that your value was an array of threads thus needing to be indexed.

Here is your working code, just one letter difference ;-) and a couple of brackets...

```
function readBotsEmail()
{
  var emails = GmailApp.search("label:" + incoming);

  Logger.log("This is the 'emails' object:" + emails)


  var emailsLoopIndex = 0
  for (var email in emails)
  {
    emailsLoopIndex += 1;
    try
    {
      Logger.log("iteration " + emailsLoopIndex + "     " + emails[email].getMessageCount());
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      Logger.log("iteration " + emailsLoopIndex + "     " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

That said, you still have a lot of work on this script to make it return something interesting... for now it informs you on the number of threads and how many message they have... Anyway, that's a good start...

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will try this later today. Now that this kink has been worked out, i can start playing around with this and see where it takes me!

Comment: You're welcome... in the mean time please consider accepting the answer. thx

Comment: That error is easy to make when coming from Python: there for email in emails would mean email was one object of the list of emails. In Java it is a shortcut to refer to the index. Not evident at all that this nearly English sentence is the same as the for i=0,i<emails.length,i++ form.